# Como usar expressão regular sem usar a classe Regex?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, winforms

Preciso validar a entrada de valores e strings, porém tenho dúvidas de como usar sem usar a classe Regex, como posso obter a solução?

```
var CampoExpressao = new Regex(@"[0-9]");
```

Acima tem um código de exemplo de expressão regular.

Comment: Isso é como perguntar como se anda em um carro sem rodas. Se você não for usar essa classe, você terá que implementar toda a lógica dela de qualquer jeito - e isso é complexo o suficiente para uma tese de doutorado. Então, fica a dúvida: por que você não deseja usar essa classe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite, amigo. Creio que você esteja confundindo com Javascript. No Javascript é possível criar uma expressão regular apenas o padrão fechado entre barras

```
var re = /ab+c/;
```

ou com a classe RegExp

```
var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
```

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Na linguagem C# você sempre usará a classe Regex.

Para maiores esclarecimentos consulte o Guia de Expressões Regulares do .NET oficial da Microsoft, que você pode encontrar [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)